# Is AJAX jquery post data safe for browser/client-side manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

test code like this.  I have 2 pages.  In first page,...

```
<head>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                                  type: 'POST',
                                  url: 'test2.php',
                                  data: { name: 'doflamingo'},
                                  success: function(response) {
                                    $('body').html(response);
                                  }
                              });
            });
        });
</head>
<body>
        <input type="button" value="Click" id="btn">
</body>
```

and in test2.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name']
?>
```

If I click button on the first page  it will show the "doflamingo" text.
but if I go to Firebug of browser  and edit the 'doflamingo' to 'luffy'  and click the button   it still show the 'doflamingo'.  So this mean  AJAX jquery is secure from hack right? I don't need to add more security right?
 Also I edit url from test2.php to random.php  but the url still be the 'test2.php

Comment: You can add breakpoints in network tab and actually modify the function/variables for that instance. There are many ways to tamper the data. Also there are many tools available like Tamper monkey, Grease Monkey!

Comment: "Inspect" what element?  Modifying the DOM isn't going to change the code.  And what is this "security" you're talking about?  What are you trying to secure?  If you're testing whether or not users can modify JavaScript or send custom values to your server, your test is invalid.  Users can *do whatever they want in their own browsers*.

Comment: I think your question is not well answered. What is InspectElement browser?

Comment: No it is not secure. There are many ways to tamper with post data before it reaches the server

Comment: InspectElement browser is  Firebug.   for example, in the Google Chrome you can right-click on the webpage and choose Inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is correct , because javascript is loaded in browser memory once it's loaded .

So if you do the same getting the value of an html element this will be change.

There are some points to consider security :

browsers by default they implement the HTTP access control (CORS) see more reference here :
[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

So essentially that means by default you just can recibe request from your own domain.

But , what if you once page is loaded and you try to inject javascript malicious code in f.example inspector of browser? The request will came from a user , so you can't known if this request is a valid request or not...

This is called CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) or XCSRF ( with ajax ) .

A simple way to try handle it , can be a check for the request has been done with a good behavior ...

F.example , you got a page where first is render and then the user will do a request :

- Server side execute script and send the html to browser ,so we we can attach a indentifier of that "rendered page"

  ```
  /**
  * Preventing CSRF
  */

  $time = time();
  $_SESSION['time'] = $time;

  $salt = 'gxYrE9G5kxlPcPOC1DSTWOehgw9Rb6FQ9q2qr5vpCPhBV418Q9TUYUK91cvd';
  $_SESSION['token']= sha1($salt . $time);
  ...attach this token in a hidden input on html
  ```
- Page now is rendered with a token inside an hidden input or meta tag or whatever , so when you make the ajax request you must include this token back to a server and check against you've stored before send html :

  ```
  $_POST['crsf'] !==$_SESSION['token']
  ```

Never trust in a user request , filter all data  , and you can do as meany checks as you can , for example minimun Request Throttling , ( just storing the diff in time between request and if this is greater form n seconds discard ... ).

So definitely your answer is not , ajax is not secure for browser / client manipulation as any isn't technology   100% free of security issues.